# Dynamics 365 Project template not loading activities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

We have a MS Dynamics Project template with project tasks. Within the project template/project tasks we have activity tasks. When we use this project template in a new project the project template/project tasks/activity tasks do not come in to the new project. Looking for help.

I have added fields to the entity to calculate % complete of the activity tasks for the project template/project tasks. And also rolled up the project tasks/activity tasks completion to the project. This is working fine.

Please help with getting project template/project tasks/activity tasks to load from Project Template to new project.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Microsoft has replied to my with using a template does not copy over activities.

Comment: Does any know how to use a process to copy templates when from a template when the template is used?

Comment: @chadrexin Would you be able to help